# Determining the acceleration of a particle

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, homework

> A particle travels along a straight line with a velocity of
> $V(t) = 3 e^{t/2}\,x\,\sin⁡(2\,t)$ m/s. Determine the acceleration of the particle at t = 2 seconds.

V=3e^(0.5 t) x sin(2t)
A=1.5^(0.5t) x sin(2t) + 3e^(0.5t) x 2cos(2t) Sub t=2
A=1.5SIN(4) + 6ECOS(4)
A=16.73 IF DEGREES OR -11.79593 IF RADIANS

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide your `code` so that we may help you :)

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question and provided my calculation, which I feel is not correct.

Comment: That is an image, can you please provide your code in a copy and paste-able format (I.e. your Mathematica code in a code block, or at least plain-text if you do not understand how to form a code-block in markdown)? Posting your code in a copy and paste-able format is better than in an image because more are able to attempt to help you. With an image, many will not bother to try to type out the code themselves. This saves time for all involved, to post code in a copy and paste-able format.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. Is just I did not know how to add code.

Comment: If you edit your post with the plain-text, I will edit it & wrap it in the ```` marks necessary to place it in a code-block. This will help you to learn how to do this :)

Comment: I have edited, maybe ok now?

Comment: are you using Wolfram Mathematica? It does not appear that you are from the code you have posted.

Comment: Yes, tried to use it as reference to help. Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: No worries, no trouble :) also is this a homework problem? You should further mark it as such.

Comment: . Have pages of questions, getting ready for mock exam. I got bogged on about 5 questions. this is one of them. It may not come up at all, but like to know for myself. There are 4 possible answers:  -1.03 ms^(-2),  -0.01 ms^(-2),  2.49 ms^(-2),  3.51 ms^(-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of your original edit, and your question as it is written, I offer you the following:

```
v[x_,t_]:=3*Exp[-t/2]*x*Sin[2*t];
a=D[v[x,t],t]
a/.t->2//N
```

> `-1.02515 x`

First I define the velocity function, after this I take the derivative wrt time, t, then I use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) to sub in the value of t, `N` is finally used to give a numerically approximate value to the output, by “piping” everything before `//` into that function. This is equivalent to wrapping the whole line with `N[...]`.

I notice however that your options do not include the `x` variable that you have in your equation. You should be careful of this when you are translating your functions between media, i.e., from paper to computer & back again, or between software.

You should also be aware that `Sin`, by default, uses radians. I would rarely expect to use degrees in such a function, but it is possible by using `Degrees`, as in, `Sin[90 Degrees]`.

Comment: I will chew myself through this and work on similar question to practice more. Greatly appreciate your time, patient and help.

Comment: @Alif thank you! If you found this helped you, do kindly provide an upvote and accept the answer by clicking the up arrow and clicking the checkmark to turn it green :)